# How can I automatically push code to Azure WebSites when I push to my BitBucket GIT Repository?

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

I know this is possible using AppHarbor. BitBucket has a service specifically for AppHarbor which I believe notifies them to pull the latest revision when I push to my repository.

Is there a way to setup a similar workflow using Windows Azure Websites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update (10/27/2012): as it turns out, the bitbucket support for public git repros just became available today, so give it a try!

---

Currently this is only supported for Github and Codeplex, but the Bitbucket support is around the corner. Initially, it will only support public repos, but the private repo support won't be too far behind. Can't give exact dates, but normally it should all happen before the end of the year.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I didn't specify that I need it for private repos. But because of your response I noticed a bunch of other new stuff recently deployed in the new Azure management portal. Good stuff!

Comment: See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeT2TB6fCqE&feature=youtu.be&hd=1. Just for you! :)

Comment: Good to hear private repo support is coming. For now Azure just says "There are no repositories in your Bitbucket account." if you don't have any public repos.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another good resource:

http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/continuous-deployment-with-windows-azure-websites-and-bitbucket/